# How the slide down animation will work the reverse

Tags: android, animation

I am working on android animation slide down its working fine but i need that should work just the reverse, means it should open from bottom to top currently its opening from top to bottom.

My Code is:

```
<scale
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691188/android-text-view-transition/35691469#35691469

Comment: Thank you so much @saeed

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are navigating from activity One to activity Two.
Just add this code to your animation file in anim folder

slide_up_from_bottom.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

Then you need to make a blank animation

no_animation.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

then add below line to your Activity Two onCreate method before setContentView(layoutId)

```
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_from_bottom, R.anim.no_animation);
```

Hope this helps.