# Animation effect not working bottom to top

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating phonebook like default android device .

I have already tired all possible solution available on this site but none of help me.

When user click on contact name , new layout should be open top to bottom.

But when I click on listItem animation not come bottom to top and layout does not display. However when I click again it show to effect of top to bottom sliding.

I found some problem here because when I put run without below animation its working fine.

**bottom_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate android:fromYDelta="75%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:fillAfter="true"
 android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Below is my code

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hidden_panel"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#2196F3"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgBack"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>


  hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.hidden_panel);
        hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        isPanelShown = false;


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isPanelShown==false)
                {
                Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.bottom_up);
            ViewGroup hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.hidden_panel);
            hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
            hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isPanelShown=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.anim.bottom_down);
                ViewGroup hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.hidden_panel);
                hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
                hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                isPanelShown=false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please post the code where you load the animation and make it start

Comment: i dont know may it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/35691469/3790150you

Comment: `not working already tried